# how to copy file from android device to pen drive?

Tags: android

I am trying to develop an app which copies the files from android device to pen drive. My device has provision to connect the pen drive facility. Now I am able to get the list of all connected usb devices. But I don't know how to copy the file to particular device..Any idea or link would be helpful that I can use to learn about these things..

Comment: then just push files from adb to your device command is adb push filename /external_sdcard/ further you can create loop to send all the files

Comment: @raj I have to do it from application without using adb.

Comment: See this link 

1) http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/accessory.html 2) https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html

Comment: Android does not support pen drives. You have to implement mass storage and a filesystem in your app on top of the low level usb apis. This question has been asked here many times before.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I just visited developer.android.com.. Can I use UsbManager and UsbAccessory classes for this??

Comment: Not without doing a huge amount of work. As I said before, this has been covered here many times before.  Expect your question to be closed as a duplicate of one of the others.